# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement - скажите пжл, что пропустил?

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0;

alert("Привет, угадаешь загадку?");

var riddle1 = prompt("Зимой и летом - одним цветом.\nЧто это?");
if (riddle1 == "ель" || riddle1 == "елка") {
  alert("А ты молодец! Верно.");
  i++;
  break; // ошибка тут

} else {
  alert("А вот и неправильно\nДавай угадаем еще 3 загадки.");
}

var riddle2 = prompt("Летом серый, зимой белый.\nКто это?")
if (riddle2 == "Заяц" || riddle2 == "заяц") {

  alert("Это правильный ответ");
  i++;
} else {
  alert("Не угадал(((");
}
```

Comment: А где же ваш цикл?

Comment: Не "пропустил", а добавил лишнего. Уберите строчку `break;`.

Comment: мне нужно - первая загадка - игрок дал правильный ответ - завершить "игра окончена" и не переходить к следующим загадкам